# Как называются жители Пруссии?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я вчера спрашивала об австрийцах, и мне сказали, что "австрияк" - это презрительное название. А как же тогда назвать жителей Пруссии? Прусак или пруссак - это тоже презрительное?
Спасибо

Comment: Если жителя Австрии можно звать австрияк, тогда жителя Пруссии можно звать пруссяк.

Если жителя Австрии можно звать австриец, тогда жителя Польши можно звать польшиец.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пруссия - пруссак, Польша - поляк, Тула - туляк - суффикс АК/ЯК в этом случае является нейтральным и не несет отрицательного значения. (Выбор подходящего суффикса зависит от основы).

Если же основа допускает два варианта образования слова, то они могут относиться к разным стилям, как в случае "австриец - австрияк".

Возможно, отрицательное значение суффикс АК/ЯК в этом варианте приобретает под влиянием таких слов, как  "ветряк, медяк, четвертак, косяк, кругляк", которые характерны для разговорной  речи или просторечия.